# How to create Event based application in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, events, laravel-5

I have to create a event based application in laravel 5. example:

1. A new user has signed up   - a event should be fired to notify admin
2. A comment was posted       - a event should be fired to notify all
   subscriber
3. A user creates a blog post -a event should be fired to notify admin to    approve it
4. A user likes a photo       -a event should be fired to notify creator

Comment: With help of socket.io and laravel events you can achieve the features u wanted.

Comment: Have a look at that https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events and that https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events

Comment: @Cowboy can u tell any best documentation for learning.

Comment: checkout https://laracasts.com/